# Python: Convert pandas df to hdf5 with try/except loop

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, try-except

Try to run over a df that is 150 cols and 700000 rows, col by col and appending each col to a .hdf5 file. How do I work in a try/except loop that simply prints the exception, skips that col and continues to the next one? Right now I have this:

```
def appendto_hdf5(df):
    _df = df
    for col in _df:
        try:
            _df[col].to_hdf('data.h5', 'df', format='table', data_columns=True, mode = 'a')
        except (Exception) as e:
            print(e)
            pass
```

Which works until the first exception, then just quits (probably because I dont have anything below the exception?

Comment: why are you adding column-by-column ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html) for the whole DataFrame?

Comment: `pass` in the except suite should let execution continue.

Comment: @MaxU & @wwii; There are variable names that contain `/` and mixed-integer, which results in `TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [Varname] because its data contents are [mixed-integer] object dtype`. I want to skip those. But, when I run the above code & `hdf5_df = pd.read_hdf('data.h5')`& `hdf5_df.shape` the shape is `(1000,)` indicating that it is not appending correctly.

Comment: @TMorville, AFAIK you can’t add columns - it’s not supported. Theoretically you could transpose your DF so columns turn rows, but in this case you won’t be able to add new rows , but only columns. Can you provide a small reproducible data set? I think there must be a better option

Comment: @MaxU, that explains it. Thanks. Afraid I cant even provide the header of the data, as its under a NDA. It is 150 cols of heterogeneous data, with annoying col labels like `Has/has not y` or `NewVar1`. Further, in the data, loads of semi-colons, dashes & comma annotated numbers in random places.